# Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

While creating a table dynamically by using jquery I got the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

I created table by using JavaScript

```
document.createElement('table');
document.createElement('thead');
document.createElement('tbody');
```

then called jQuery Datatable by:

```
$(mytableid).DataTable()
```

I got the table displayed. But I didn't get table filters and pagination.

Comment: not enough info... please be more specific.

Comment: You should avoid simply dumping your code and asking people to debug it. :/

Comment: Also, you haven't actually provided the code that is generating the error.  There is no instance of the string `mData` in the code you've provided.

Comment: Actually the mData is a property from jquery datatable plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for considering my question.

I got a solution for the above issue.

Before creating a new data table, I removed it's container div and created a new one. It helps to remove the previously created data tables and it's related html tags of same signature.

I think this would be the reason for that error....